No GUI after updating to Noble numbat
i just updated my LTS ubuntu System after i got a prompt saying there is a new version.
Turned out to be a mistake because now Ubuntu boots without a GUI and if I do startx the screen just gets smaller and freezes.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is my main work laptop and I can only suspect that the update broke other things as well.
The only thing I found online, is that lightdm might have trouble and i believe i use that (not certain)
Thanks in advance

Please run sudo apt update followed by sudo apt full-upgrade and sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^

Ive got a log of "Sorry Ubuntu 24.04 has expirienced an internal error" messages popping up but at least the GUI seems to be eorking again. Thank you very much :)
